# converting a string array to a double array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I am trying to convert a list of numbers from a txt file into an array of numbers. There is 26 numbers, and each is on a different line in the text file. My code is

```
import java.io.*;
public class rocket {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/Users/Jeremy/Documents/workspace/altitude.txt")));
        String[] stringArray = new String[25];
        double[] doubleArray = new double[stringArray.length];
        for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
        {
            stringArray[i] = b.readLine();
            doubleArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<doubleArray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(doubleArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

But every time I run it I get a number format exception. And if I try to just print out the strings I get an indexOutOfBounds exception

Comment: if there are 26 numbers you should be doing this `new String[26]`. This is causing the `indexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: readLine() returns a string with the linebreak appended.
Also, you don't need to create a string array. You can use 1 tempString variable inside the loop. Not sure how you'd handle the double[] size though, because I don't know Java.
**edit:**
For the doubles, use a vector.

Comment: I thought that the count started at the "zeroeth" term? And @Magtheridon96, I don't know how to do that, but I would appreciate it if you put that into an answer

Comment: @user1940007 They do however you are specifying the size here. You want 26 elements. Not 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(
                            "D:/git-repo/general/misc_test/src/java/com/greytip/cougar/module/test/v2/controller/so/dump/data.txt")));

    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }

    String[] stringArray = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    double[] doubleArray = new double[stringArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        doubleArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < doubleArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(doubleArray[i]);
    }
```

Comment: still has a NumberFormatException

Comment: can you share the text file

Comment: the file is just 60 2927 10170 21486 33835 45251 55634 65038 73461 80905 87368 92852 97355 100879 103422 104986 106193 110247 119626 136106 162096 199506 238776 277065 314375 350704 each number is on another line

Comment: Works, I realized that my file wasn't a pure txt file

Answer (score 2):

in question you have mentioned that there is 26 strings so declate

```
String[] stringArray = new String[26];
```

And The number format exception is occuring as readline returns with the linbreak. To read line you can do the following

```
 public String[] readLines(String filename) throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    }
```

So by this logic you can get double by

```
public static Double[] readLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    List<Double> lines = new ArrayList<Double>();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    return lines.toArray(new Double[lines.size()]);
}
```

Comment: The rest of my method will be using derivatives, so I need the array to be a double, and this returns a string array.

Comment: I just showed how you can parse the line .. from this string array you can modify the code to get double array

Comment: So I put this in the main, and directly copied and pasted the method that returns a double, and I still get the error message NumberFormatException `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(readLines("/Users/Jeremy/Documents/workspace/altitude.txt")));`

Comment: :s.. just print the return values in system.out.print(readLines(filename)); if there is stil problem.. show the file

Comment: the file is just                                                        60
2927
10170
21486
33835
45251
55634
65038
73461
80905
87368
92852
97355
100879
103422
104986
106193
110247
119626
136106
162096
199506
238776
277065
314375
350704 each number is on another line

Comment: is there an blank line at the end

Comment: @user1940007 do one thing. create a simple file with just 1 2 3 in each line then try. coz my code should definitely work

Comment: I have been using an RTF file that I converted to a TXT file in the wrong way. I just converted it correctly and with your program it prints out _[Ljava.lang.Double;@35960f05_ but it doesn't have an error

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] stringArray = new String[26];
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class Rocket {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
        {
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/Users/Jeremy/Documents/workspace/altitude.txt")));
            String[] stringArray = new String[25];
            double[] doubleArray = new double[stringArray.length];
            for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
            {
                stringArray[i] = b.readLine();
                try{
                    doubleArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[i]);
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i<doubleArray.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(doubleArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Handle the Exception when parse a string to double please.